# Specific Denormalization techniques for a data set

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, denormalization

I'm working on a school project, and for extra credit we can add a database to our android app. I'm using Firebase because I've heard a lot about it so I wanted to learn how to use it!

I've been reading up on how to organize data in it and I have a few questions about my specific use case, and am hoping to find some advise.

For our project, we need to have a list of locations that each have properties associated with them (address, name, what they do etc) and also a list of users at those locations. I currently have location as one of my "category". I don't know the proper word for this, what I mean is that in my json file it looks like this:

`{ "Locations": { "location_1": {...}, "location_2": {...} ...} }`

As well as, I have users as another category in my json file.

I'm wondering what is the best way to go about keeping track of users in a location? I was thinking to just keep another property in a location that's called like "occupants" or something, but I don't know if that's nesting data too deeply or not.

Comment: If you only requirement is to get the users in a specific Location, you approach is fine. If, on the other hand, you would like to query something like: all the Locations a User is in, you would have to denormalize further. Just tell me and in this case I would be happy to elaborate a more detailed answer.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I would have to get both the location a user is in and all users in a location. In that case, would I have the user hold a location parameter, and then have the value be "location_id: true"?

Answer (score 0):

Following your comment above when you explain that you "would have to get both the location a user is in and all users in a location.", you have to create two data structures:

One for the Users in which you store the current user location:

```
- Users
  - User_A
    - Location: Location_1
  - User_B
    - Location: Location_2
```

and one for the Locations, when you list, for each location the list of users being at this location.

```
- Location_1
  - "Users": {
    "alovelace": true,
    "ghopper": true,
    "eclarke": true
  }
```

With NoSQL database you should not hesitate to duplicate data in such a way your queries are easy and fast to execute.

I would suggest thatyou have a look at this recent Firebase video where this approach is very well explained (the video is about Firestore, but look at the first 9 minutes): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ